# Streaming video from raspberri pi to the internet

Tags: python, rest, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, webcam

I'm working on my first big raspberry pi project and I've hit a roadblock I can't get past. I'm using REST API to control my raspberry pi from website remotely over the internet and now I'd like to add a video streaming feature (nothing fancy) but I can't find mutch info about this on the internet. The problem I have is that i can't figure out how to transmit the frames (from what I've learned it has to be jpeg images not a real video) and how to actualy display them on the webpage. So far i can view the stream only in localhost and i have no idea how to get it out to my webpage on the internet webhosting.

I've tried to send the frames using requests library in python like this:

```
img_for_post = stream.read()    
data = {'image': img_for_post, 'name':'webcan_stream'}
response = requests.post(url='http://my-website-on-the-internet.com/index.php?stream', data=data)
```

but it doesn't seem to be sending the images. I'm tring to do it with rest api because i can't (and don't want to) use port forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

> from what I've learned it has to be jpeg images not a real video

No, the opposite is true.  Where did you read this?  Sending JPEG frames is horribly inefficient.  If you must use JPEG for some reason, at least send an MJPEG stream.

Depending on your needs, it's actually trivial to just start FFmpeg and pipe it directly to your browser client over HTTP.  I don't remember the exact command line that I used to use, but try something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i [your source] -f webm -
```

That will output WebM video out of STDOUT,  Then, in your Python script, just pipe that data to the HTTP client.

On the client, they can just use a normal video tag:

```
<video src="https://example.com/stream" preload="none"></video>
```

Other ways you can do this include DASH/HLS which is useful for more users or using a CDN, or WebRTC if you need low latency.

Comment: Hi, so I've got to the point where I can stream a video from my webcam to a website but it still doesn't play. After tring hls (too long latency and too much unstable) I've decided to simply stream .mov or .mp4 or .mpeg file to the ftp and then play it as it is being "created" by ffmpeg running on my computer. Problem with that is that the video in unplayble in the browser. It plays when i download it but not in the browser. The error message tels me that the mime type is not supported. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Muhaha Skip the FTP, skip HLS, just pipe that output stream directly to the client.  That's all you need to do.

Comment: But how? What is the pipe I've never heard of it. The ffmpeg documentation mentions it but doesn't go into detail.

Comment: In your Python application, I'm not sure, I'm not a Python guy.  All you need to do though is read from STDOUT.  When you run `ffmpeg` with `-` as the output filename, you can take that STDOUT stream and in your Python application, pipe it into the stream you're sending back to the client.  Or, just read and write chunks... same thing.  I don't know how you do that in Python but surely you can.

Comment: I'm not streaming in the python aplication. I'm using REST API. The python application just sends POST and GET requests to the remote website (client). Rest API doesn't really do video streaming if I understand it correctly. I thought that by saveing the video fille on to an ftp server (client) from ffmpeg and then just plaing it from there as its being created woud spare me having to learm websockets.

Comment: You don't need web sockets for one-way communication.  A normal HTTP response is fine.

Comment: Ok, so I've been looking into it for a while now and I'm certain that  i CAN NOT simply stream STDOUT to a website that doesn't have websockets installed as you suggested. So I've decided to use nodejs, websockets hosting for this project. From what I've learned so far live video streaming is notoriously dificult and tutorials I've found on this topic dont seem to work for me. Closest I've got is by following this: https://github.com/sbidolach/video-live-streaming but I've only been eble go get a gray webpage as an output. If anybody has some experience with this I would appreciate any advice.